# show vertical graph in apex column

Tags: visualforce

I have a application object with status as a picklist field. 
The values are Draft and Submitted.

In a page block table in status column.. i want to show a vertical bar of different color based on status value

[image]

Class Code

```
public with sharing class theController
{
    public List<Application__c> lstApplication{get;set;} 
    public Application__c applicationsrequest{get;set;}
    String Color;

    public OAOARequestHistory()
    {                       
        lstApplication = [SELECT Id, Name, Editor__c,Status__c 
                            FROM Application__c];

        if(lstApplication != null && lstApplication.size()>0)
        {
            this.applicationsrequest = lstApplication[0];                 
        }                   

        if(applicationrequest.Status__c == "Submitted")
        {
            Color="green";
        }
        if(applicationrequest.Status__c == "Draft")
        {
            Color="grey";
        }
    }   
 }
```

How do i pass value of colr from apex class to the td background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have only two values in pick list you can do this as:

```
    <table>
     <tr>
       <td style="background-color:{!IF(applicationrequest.Status__c == 'Draft','grey','green')};">
      </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```